# VBA Creation error: Sub Not Defined

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I have tried to create a macro for CorelDraw, using Microsoft VB for applications(VBA). I have a form set up and a block of code in the "form1" window. This is meant to create a circle when the generate button is clicked but it says

> "sub or function not defined"

for this line of below code

```
PRIVATE SUB GENERATE_CLICK().
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ("Badge 1")
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ("Badge 2")
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ("Badge 3")
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ("Badge 4")
End Sub

Private Sub Generate_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Badge 1" Then B1
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Badge 2" Then B2
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Badge 3" Then B3
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Badge 4" Then B4
End Sub

Sub B1()
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim w As Double
    Dim h As Double

    ActiveLayer.CreateEllipse w, h
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a `B2`, `B3`, and `B4` subroutine?

Comment: Not yet may that be the problem?

Comment: Yup, that's a problem.

Comment: ok so another question real quick.

Comment: Im trying to create a circle with this code: "ActiveLayer.CreateEllipse.Fill.UniformColor.RGBBlue"  and get a message saying arguement not optiona;

Comment: Submit a new question and be sure to include the tag `CorelDraw`. That will get you to the right audience.